# Keycloak Internal Server Error when a user tries to register with an existing email

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-settings

As the title says, when registering a new account within a realm there's no email uniqueness check and keycloak give an internal server error

```
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UK_DYKN684SL8UP1CRFEI6ECKHD7'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.USER_ENTITY'. The duplicate key value is (my_realm, user@email.com).
```

my realm settings are these

[image]

and duplicate emails switch is disabled.

how can I enforce a unique email check like the unique username one?

Comment: Could you try to disable `Login with email` and/or the latest Keycloak version `12.0.4` with setup from the scratch.

Answer (score 3):

We had the same issue and even the developer who was assigned to the Jira ticket I created couldn't find it. Because the issue did not show up in a clean installation of Keycloak we suspected it to be data related, and I only found it after eliminating pretty much everything I could think of.

Solution: go to menu Configure > Authentication > tab: Flows > dropdown: Registration and set Profile Validation to ENABLED.

It was disabled in our case, which caused Keycloak to skip the email validation that the Realm settings > Login form suggests should be active.